# Calling functions from a list issue

Tags: python

I am making a project that involves calling functions from a list, but I can't get it to work straight. There is some problem with calling the functions from the list, and I just can't seem to figure out why. I have some code below for an example, and the output will be provided as well. The code provided is just an example of the basic idea of what I am trying to do. It is not my actual code. Don't worry though, it is the basic idea.

```
import random, time
def word1():
    print "Hello"

def word2():
    print "Goodbye"

words = [word1(), word2()]

def run():
    while True:
        random.choice(words)()
        time.sleep(0.5)
run()
```

And the output I get is this:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

For all I know, this could be some simple error that I am overlooking, but for the life of me, can not figure out. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the function *results* in the list<sup>1</sup>, not the functions themselves.

i.e. change:

```
words = [word1(), word2()]
```

to:

```
words = [word1, word2]
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>And the results are all `None` which is why you get the `NoneType` not callable error...</sup>

Answer (score 3):

"`word1()`" is not the function `word1`; it is instead the return value from calling `word1()`, which, because `word1` doesn't explicitly return anything, is `None`.  What's `word1`?  It's just `word1`.  Thus, the declaration of `words` should be changed from:

```
words = [word1(), word2()]
```

to:

```
words = [word1, word2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the functions already within the list. You want to defer.

```
words = [word1, word2]
def run():
  while True:
    random.choice(words)()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```