# Calling functions one by one from a python list

Tags: python

I have a list of functions say

```
list1 = ['foo','boo','koo']
```

now I want to call these functions one by one.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i](<argumentslist>)
```

This gives me an error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

How Should I make this possible ?

Comment: "I have a list of functions" -- Not exactly, it looks like you have a list of strings.  How you convert those strings to functions depends on a lot of things but my guess is that it'll probably involve either using `getattr` or `globals` (Or, you could actually create a list of functions rather than a list of strings that represent functions in one way or another).

Comment: The list item are names of functions?

Comment: Not again. This is technically possible, but it is **very bad design**... Call-by-name is very insecure

Comment: You need to use a list of actual functions -eg. `list1 = [foo,boo,koo]`, not a list of names of functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling functions from a list issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875834/calling-functions-from-a-list-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `'` in the list

```
list1 = [foo,boo,koo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is does not contain a function objects, you are storing a string. Functions are first class object in python. If you want to store it as a list and call them use the function object as follows.
`list = [foo, bar ]
list[0](args)`

Answer (score 0):

Currently the elements in your list are strings. Given that you have defined functions `foo`, `boo`, `koo` you can put these in a list without the`'` surrounding them. I.e. you will be making a list of functions, not a list of string function names.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but:

```
def hello_world(int_):
    print("hello{}".format(int_))

list_ = ["hello_world"]
arg = 2

for i in list_:
    exec("{}({})".format(i,arg))

#hello2
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to remove the quotes if you use `**kwargs`:

```
def the_function(**functions): 

    list1 = ['foo','boo','koo']
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        val = functions[list1[i]](3)

f1 = lambda x: pow(x, 2)
f2 = lambda x: x+3
f3 = lambda x: sum(i for i in range(x))

the_function(foo = f1, boo = f2, koo = f3)
```